# Passing Non-Command Line parameters to TornadoFX App in Kotlin

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm fairly new to developing GUIs, and especially new to JavaFX/TornadoFX, and I'm not really sure how to do what I'm trying to do.

The gist is I'm trying to make a small IDE, and I want to be able to provide the TornadoFX App a particular Interpreter for the IDE:

`class IDE(i: Interpreter) : App(IDEView::class)`

But this doesn't work, since the configuration to run the App in IntelliJ just points to the IDE class, and doesn't specify what the parameter is.

Why I try to run it, basically it complains that the IDE class did not get the arguments it needs, but there is no way (in the configuration to run the App in IntelliJ) to specify parameters. If I create my own main and manually use:

`launch<IDE>()`

I can pass arguments, but the only thing it accepts are command line args (like an Array of Strings).

I'm planning on trying to follow the MVC pattern as closely as possible, and the Interpreter (interface) here is basically the Model behind everything. This is a project I'm working on with a friend, so he's working on the Model, and I'm going to be making the Controller and View. If there's no "clean" way to provide a custom Model, then I can just hard code it straight into the App, but I'd prefer to avoid that (and learn how to do it properly).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I've edited the post to include more context about why it doesn't work, but the error it's giving me is basically that it needs the argument in order to instantiate an IDE object, but I don't know of any way to supply it.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, you want to pass `Intepreter` instance in `IDE` constructor, but because that class is being developer by your friend you can't use it yet?

Comment: No, the interface is defined so I'm just going to develop it using that (I created an anonymous instance of the Interpreter interface), the issue is that I don't know of any way to manually instantiate the IDE object with an Interpreter object as a parameter, and then run the application. The options I know of are creating a configuration in Intellij to run the IDE class as a Java Application, or to use the launch function, which only accepts arguments in command-line args format (an Array of strings).

Comment: Not sure I follow completely, but if you want to pass non-cli parameters to the TornadoFX app, just configure a companion object/static properties with the parameters, and have the TornadoFX app pick them up from there?